# Custom ordering Core Data to-many relationship?

Tags: core-data

How can I sorting by a 'custom' order managed object in a to-many relationship? It seems managed objects are in an arbitrary order, and I need them ordered alphabetically by `name` property. Shall I extend managed object / entity?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, managed objects in Core Data are in no particular order.  You can order them when you fetch by setting the `sortDescriptors` property on the fetch request.  If you are already doing a fetch, that is faster and more efficient than fetching first and then sorting in memory, for example, by calling `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`.

So, if you were to fetch all Events, you would do as follows:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Event.name),
                                                 ascending: true)]
```

Or, if you have a many-to-many relationship from Events to Users that is called usersWhoLiked, you could fetch all events that were liked by at least one user over age 50 as follows:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "@"SUBQUERY(usersWhoLiked, $user, $user.age > %d).@count != 0",
                50))
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Event.name),
                                                 ascending: true)]
```

But, note that the sortDescriptors apply ONLY to the fetch request's entity.  And, if you are not doing a fetch at all, for example just ordering all the events of a particular user, then Jon Rose's solution may be just as efficient or more.

It's unclear what exactly you want to order.  I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is defined as a set, which is unordered.  You can turn the set into an array and then sort the array:

```
NSArray* sortedEvents = [user.events.allObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]]
```